# All models failed Modeltime Calibration

Tags: r, forecasting

I am running a code from the [blog](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/07/forecasting-many-time-series-using-no-for-loops/#google_vignette). I got stuck at step modeltime_calibrate()

My code and data file are in this [drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tfQ6VqiStso5rMCT3pu3zg4tMuf6O7BG?usp=sharing)

`calib_tbl <- model_tbl %>%`
  `modeltime_calibrate(`
   `new_data = testing(splits),`
    `id       = "ID",`
    `quite = FALSE`
  `)`
`calib_tbl`

I tried to run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Voting to close as not containing sufficient details. Using an external link for the code is not likely to result in a durable question. The code might 'evaporate' in at any time.